# flutter location get error when add in pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, flutter, location

I add  location:  3.2.4 to my pubsepec.yaml and i have this error "The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility"

i add the **multiDexEnabled true** to the defaultConfig in android stdiou and android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true to the gradle.properties and migrate to the android dx but i get still this error

> The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a
> plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
> incompatibility

can anybody help me to solve this problem?

and this is my build.gradel :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.Amirmasoud.marketer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your build.gradle files? Maybe you have an line error?

Comment: yes i edit my question @ChrisPi

Comment: Could you also provide the complete error? Usually, you see a bit more than what you have put.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't change anything in this `build.gradle`. Have you added the location permissions in the `AndoidManifest.xml` ? Also have you tried `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`?

Comment: but i see some result in stackoverflow and they change the build.gradle for Android x problem @ChrisPi

Comment: Yeah and if it have worked for you, you wouldnt be here. You shouldnt randomly change things in the gradle files if you dont know what you do. So do you want my help or do you research on your own and then tell me whats in other stackoverflow threads which doesnt helped you?